# Uploading file using multipartformentity to php script (file ends up in $_POST)

Tags: php, android, multipartentity

I have an android app which uses the multipartentity from apache httpcomponents.  The app uploads a file using an HTTP request to a php script.  However, the file that I am uploading (.ogg) ends up in $_POST instead of $_FILES and it looks like binary, although I could be wrong.

I have the chrome rest extension and I used it to POST a multipart/form-data request with the exact same .ogg file and the file ends up in the correct spot ($_FILES).

Android code is as follows:

```
// Send the file to the server.
// Create HTTP objects.
// Request.
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ACTION);

// Response.
HttpResponse httpResponse;

httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(mediaFile, "audio/ogg");
mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);

httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);

// Execute.
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

// Evaluate the response.
int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

// Make sure everythings okay.
if (statusCode == 200) {
     HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
     if (resEntity != null) {
          String body = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
          resEntity.consumeContent();
          Log.d("APP_STATUS", body);
     }
}

httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

And the very simple PHP script:

```
<?php
echo "\$_POST";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "\$_FILES";
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Response when using the app:

[image]

Response when using the Chrome REST extension:

[image]

If anyone has any insight to what I'm failing epicly at, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have access to `MultipartEntityBuilder`?

Comment: I believe so, the code I used was from a similar situation except they were uploading an image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the entity builder

```
HttpEntity mpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .addBinaryBody(
      "file", cbFile, ContentType.create("audio/ogg"), cbFile.getName())
    .build();
```